# matplotlib taking time when being imported

Tags: python, matplotlib

I just upgraded to the latest stable release of `matplotlib` (1.5.1) and everytime I import matplotlib I get this message:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py:273: UserWarning: Matplotlib is building the font cache using fc-list. This may take a moment.
  warnings.warn('Matplotlib is building the font cache using fc-list. This may take a moment.')
```

... which always stalls for a few seconds.

Is this the expected behaviour? Was it the same also before, but just without the printed message?

Comment: relevant: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/5640. The suggestion there is to delete the contents of `~/.cache/matplotlib` and try again. It may be a permissions issue - It shouldn't be building that cache every time

Comment: I hadn't read the latest comments. Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me. On Ubuntu 14.04.2 with python 2.7 I deleted all of the files in  ~/.cache/matplotlib/ .  At first I thought it didn't work because I got the warning afterward. But after the cache files were rebuilt the warning went away. :)

Comment: In a mod_wsgi+apache httpd+centos combination - when a request is sent from browser the httpd simply waits saying font cache is being built....It waits for more than 6 minutes and goes on and on....and never completes the font update. Could you please suggest how to solve this? Thanks

Answer (score 117, accepted):

As tom suggested in the comment above, deleting the files:

```
fontList.cache
fontList.py3k.cache 
tex.cache
```

solve the problem. 
In my case the files were under:

```
`~/.matplotlib`
```

EDITED

A couple of days ago the message appeared again, I deleted the files in the locations mention above without any success. I found that as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35734074/problems-with-matplotlib-is-building-the-font-cache-using-fc-list-this-may-tak) by [T Mudau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5695374/tshilidzi-mudau) there's an extra location with text cache files is: `~/.cache/fontconfig`

Comment: I am on OSX El Capitan and this does not solve the issue. Any thoughts?

Comment: On El Capitan I also had to remove ~/.cache/fontList or similar.

Comment: `mpl.get_cachedir()` will show the cache location [docs](http://matplotlib.org/faq/troubleshooting_faq.html#matplotlib-configuration-and-cache-directory-locations)

Comment: I am also on OS X El Capitan.  I noticed the first time I imported matplotlib.pyplot after removing the cache files, I still got the same error but the second time it ran much quicker.

Comment: I am on OS X El Capitan and this resolves the issue.

Comment: Note that after deleting these files you'll still get the warning one more time -- the next time you import matplotlib. After that you're set.

Answer (score 25):

Confirmed Hugo's approach works for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS/matplotlib 1.5.1:

- deleted ~/.cache/matplotlib/fontList.cache
- ran code, again the warning was issued (assumption: is rebuilding the cache correctly)
- ran code again, no more warning (finally)

Answer (score 12):

On OSX Yosemite (version 10.10.15), the following worked for me:

- remove the cache files from this directory as well: ~/.cache/fontconfig (as per tom's suggestion)
  `rm -rvf ~/.cache/fontconfig/*`
- also removed .cache files in ~/.matplotlib (as per Hugo's suggestion)
  `rm -rvf ~/.matplotlib/*`

Comment: Worked for me on macOS X El Captain. I have the impression that it made faster loading other libraries as well.

Comment: worked on macOS 10.12.  On 2nd load, don't get the message anymore.

Answer (score 9):

I ran the python code using sudo just once, and it resolved the warning for me. 
Now it runs faster. Running without sudo gives no warning at all.

Cheers

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I am running Jupyter notebook on Mac OSX El Capitan.  I ran `sudo jupyter notebook` then `import matplotlib.pyplot` in a notebook and it solved my problem.

Comment: I've been struggling with this for months and this solved it! I'm on OS 10.9.5.

Comment: Well, if you take a look at accepted answer, you'll see all you've done is that you have solved the problem by changing the user, and since there's no ~/.matplotlib in root home directory problem vanishes.

Comment: @Rsh No, the answers saying to use root permissions say that running it once as root makes it so it doesn't build the cache again if you run as a regular user after. Anyway, this didn't work for me.

Answer (score 4):

I ran the python code w. sudo and it cured it...my guess was that there wasn't permission to write that table... good luck!

Answer (score 0):

HI you must find this file : font_manager.py in my case : C:\Users\gustavo\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\ font_manager.py

and FIND def win32InstalledFonts(directory=None, fontext='ttf') and replace by :

def win32InstalledFonts(directory=None, fontext='ttf'):
    """
    Search for fonts in the specified font directory, or use the
    system directories if none given.  A list of TrueType font
    filenames are returned by default, or AFM fonts if *fontext* ==
    'afm'.
    """

```
from six.moves import winreg
if directory is None:
    directory = win32FontDirectory()

fontext = get_fontext_synonyms(fontext)

key, items = None, {}
for fontdir in MSFontDirectories:
    try:
        local = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, fontdir)
    except OSError:
        continue

    if not local:
        return list_fonts(directory, fontext)
    try:
        for j in range(winreg.QueryInfoKey(local)[1]):
            try:
                key, direc, any = winreg.EnumValue(local, j)
                if not is_string_like(direc):
                    continue
                if not os.path.dirname(direc):
                    direc = os.path.join(directory, direc)
                    direc = direc.split('\0', 1)[0]

                if os.path.splitext(direc)[1][1:] in fontext:
                    items[direc] = 1
            except EnvironmentError:
                continue
            except WindowsError:
                continue
            except MemoryError:
                continue
        return list(six.iterkeys(items))
    finally:
        winreg.CloseKey(local)
return None
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on Ubuntu **16.04 LST** with **Python 3.5.2 | Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit)**. I deleted all of the files in `~/.cache/matplotlib/`.

```
sudo rm -r fontList.py3k.cache tex.cache
```

At first I thought it wouldn't work, because I got the warning afterward. But after the cache files were rebuilt the warning went away. So, close your file, and reopen again(open again), it has no warning.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install libfreetype6-dev libxft-dev
```