# Problems with "Matplotlib is building the font cache using fc-list. This may take a moment." on MacoS

Tags: macos, matplotlib, anaconda, jupyter

I am running OS X 10.11.3, and I have installed Anaconda3-2.5.0-MacOSX-x86_64.pkg which includes Matplotlib 1.5.1.  When I try to import Matplotlib in Jupyter with the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pp
```

I get a very long error message, beginning with the following:

> /Users/hgbauer/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py:273: UserWarning: Matplotlib is building the font cache using fc-list. This may take a moment.

The message never goes away, no matter how long I wait.

I’ve noticed in a related thread:

[matplotlib taking time when being imported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34771191/matplotlib-taking-time-when-being-imported)

that the problem may require deleting the contents of ~/.cache/matplotlib, but in that situation, Matplotlib seems to have been installed separately rather than as a part of Anaconda.

My question is this:

How can I access the ~/.cache/matplotlib file in Anaconda in order to delete the contents?

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Comment: `mv ~/.matplotlib/ ~/.matplotlib_old` restart python, and if it works you remove  `~/.matplotlib/`

Answer (score 12):

The files to be removed are under `~/.matplotlib`, rather than `~/.cache/matplotlib` (you'll also want to remove `~/.cache/fontconfig` out of superstition, but the wrong `.matplotlib` path was the big thing)

You should see that pesky message again on your next run, then no more.

Answer (score 8):

You can find this out with `get_cachedir()`. For example in python 2:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
print mpl.get_cachedir()
```

and in python 3:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
print(mpl.get_cachedir())
```

[See here for more information](http://matplotlib.org/faq/troubleshooting_faq.html#matplotlib-configuration-and-cache-directory-locations)