# Removing ~./matplotlib and ~./cache/fontconfig do not resolve "Matplotlib is building the font cache"

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am on macOS Sierra (v.10.12.6). I am just starting to work with Python and have Anaconda with my base (root) version of Python as v.2.7.15. I'm trying to run a simple experiment file that uses psychopy and get what appears to be a fairly common error every time I run it:

/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py:281: UserWarning: Matplotlib is building the font cache using fc-list. This may take a moment.
  'Matplotlib is building the font cache using fc-list. '

As recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35734074/problems-with-matplotlib-is-building-the-font-cache-using-fc-list-this-may-tak) and [here](https://github.com/tmbdev/ocropy/wiki/FAQ#how-to-avoid-the-userwarning-matplotlib-is-building-the-font-cache), I have rm -rf'd ~/.matplotlib and ~/.cache/fontconfig. (~/.cache/matplotlab doesn't appear to exist.) Running the script twice after doing so (once to allow the cache to rebuild, then again to see if the issue is resolved) suggests Matplotlib is just continuing to build the font cache every time. In Anaconda Navigator, I see that I have v.2.2.3 of Matplotlib associated with my base python environment. I also tried just removing the files inside the two directories and making sure that the permissions for those two directories were rwx for all.

Ideas?

In case it is useful, the following files are generated:

- ~./matplotlib/fontList.json
- And a bunch of alphanumeric junk (all ending with .cache-7) inside
  ~./cache/fontconfig

Comment: If you are just starting to work w/ python, is there some reason you are using py2.7 instead of py3.7?  There have been improvements in the font caching issues but perhaps they have not made it back to mpl 2.2.3.  If you upgrade to py3, you should get mpl3.0.x

Comment: I originally thought PsychoPy required 2.7, but I think now I may be able to use 3.7, I'll try reinstalling things.