# Matplotlib how to set legend's font type

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to change the font type of the legend texts in Matplotlib. I know I can do something like this:

```
plt.legend(prop={'family': 'Arial'})
```

But I want to use a Chinese font type and I have no idea what is the family name I should put in the line above. But I do have a fontproperties object to that Chinese font type. However, I haven't found a way to set the fontproperties of the legend.

So two questions:

1. How to find the name of a particular font's family name
2. How to set fontproperties of the legend

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Pass the FontProperties object (such as `font` below) to `ax.legend` via the `prop` parameter:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 100)
ax.plot(np.sin(x)/x, label='Mexican hat')

font = font_manager.FontProperties(family='Comic Sans MS',
                                   weight='bold',
                                   style='normal', size=16)
ax.legend(prop=font)
plt.show()
```

### [image]

On Ubuntu, you can make new fonts available to your system by running

```
fc-cache -f -v /path/to/fonts/directory
```

I'm not sure how it is done on other OSes, or how universal `fc-cache` is on other flavors of Unix.

---

Once you've installed your font(s) so that your OS knows about them, you can cause matplotlib to [regenerate its fontList](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34999763/190597) by deleting the files in `~/.cache/fontconfig` and `~/.cache/matplotlib`.

---

The `~/.cache/matplotlib/fontList.json` file gives you a humanly-readable list of all the fonts matplotlib knows about. There, you'll find entries that look like this:

```
{
  "weight": "bold",
  "stretch": "normal",
  "fname": "/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Comic_Sans_MS_Bold.ttf",
  "_class": "FontEntry",
  "name": "Comic Sans MS",
  "style": "normal",
  "size": "scalable",
  "variant": "normal"
},
```

Notice that the `fname` is the path to the underlying ttf file, and that there is a `name` property as well. You can [specify the FontProperties object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7728665/190597) by the path to the ttf file:

```
font = font_manager.FontProperties(fname="/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Comic_Sans_MS_Bold.ttf")
```

or by name:

```
font = font_manager.FontProperties(family='Comic Sans MS',
                                   weight='bold',
                                   style='normal', size=16)
```

---

If you do not wish to install your font system-wide, you can specify the `FontProperties` object by `fname` path, thus by-passing the need to call `fc-cache` and messing with `~/.cache`.